# Pass jQuery text()-Variable to a function

Tags: jquery, spservices

I have the following issue:

I want to loop through all `<td>`-elements in the `document` and replace text with some data from Sharepoint (by using SP.Services).

```
updateData ();

function updateData () {

    $(document).find('td').each (function() {

            var contentTD = $(this).text().trim();

            if (contentTD.indexOf("ABC\\") >= 0) {

                $(this).text(getUserDataFromSP (contentTD, 'Title'));

            }

    }); 

}
```

If a specific text in `<td>` is found, it should be passed to this function:

```
function getUserDataFromSP (userName, neededInformation) {  

    var managerName;
    var user = userName;

    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetUserProfileByName",
        async: false,
        AccountName: user,
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            managerName = $(xData.responseXML).text();
            var managerLength = managerName.length;
            var indexofManager = managerName.indexOf(neededInformation);
            managerName = managerName.substring(indexofManager + 11, managerLength);
            var indexOffalse = managerName.indexOf("false");
            managerName = managerName.substring(0, indexOffalse);
        }
    });

    return managerName
}
```

The problem is, if I pass `contentTD`, it doesnt work: `getUserDataFromSP (contentTD, 'Title')`
But, if I do this, it works: `getUserDataFromSP ("ABC\\testUserName", 'Title')`

It seems like that `$(this).text().trim()` != String?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Set a `console.log(contentTD);` after setting its value to check what it actually contains.

Comment: I get `ABC\\testUserName`. To be ensured, that I'm  not blind, I have used the output of a `console.log` as a input for the `getUserDataFromSP`-formula and it has worked also :(

Comment: Not sure how to do this, general tip tho: Don't use the document selector, this searches in all of the tags, including head and so on. Better use a container for the tds (NOT good html-practice btw) and set the selector to this container.

Comment: Hello. Thx for response. Im still searching for a solution. What I have found is, that to pass a String with "\\" chars cause some problems.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was found:

I had to consider that "\" is a escape character.

So I only need to delete one "\" in the passed string:

```
contentTD = "ABC\userTestName"
```